# Confusing with LINQ and Lambda expressions in C#

Tags: c#

I am totally got confused with LINQ and Lambda expressions in C#. Please explain, what the difference in between them and when to use?

Comment: LINQ is the `select from` syntax. Can also be referring to Linq extensions methods - `Select` `ToList` etc. Lamba is the syntax of `x => ...` as an anonymous function. They are many times used together.

Comment: Thanks.. Nathan..
Is LINQ is related to writing the SQL query in C#, and Lambda are use full for manipulating the expressions in C#, is it correct.